# Python implementation of statistical Sweep operator

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am learning some techniques for doing statistics with missing data from a book (**Statistical Analysis with Missing Data** by Little and Rubin). One particularly useful function for working with monotone non-response data is the *Sweep Operator* (details on page 148-151).  I know that the R module **gmm** has the *swp* function which does this but I was wondering if anyone has implemented this function in Python, ideally for Numpy matrices to hold the input data. I searched StackOverflow and also did several web searches without success. Thanks for any help.

Here is the definition.

A PxP symmetric matrix G is said to be swept on row and column k if it is replaced by another symmetric PxP matrix H with elements defined as follows:

```
    h_kk = -1/g_kk
    h_jk = h_kj = g_jk/g_kk for j != k
    h_jl = g_jl - g_jk g_kl / g_kk j != k, l != k
        
        
    G = [g11, g12, g13
         g12, g22, g23
         g13, g23, g33]   
    H = SWP(1,G) = [-1/g11, g12/g11, g13/g11
                   g12/g11, g22-g12^2/g11, g23-g13*g12/g11
                   g13/g11, g23-g13*g12/g11, g33-g13^2/g11]
    kvec = [k1,k2,k3]
    SWP[kvec,G] = SWP(k1,SWP(k2,SWP(k3,G)))

    Inverse function
    H = RSW(k,G)
    h_kk = -1/g_kk
    h_jk = h_kj = -g_jk/g_kk for j != k
    h_jl = g_jk g_kl / g_kk j != k, l != k    

    G == SWP(k,RSW(k,G)) == RSW(k,SWP(k,G))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a precise definition of the operation instead of just referring to a book I doubt many people here have read.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could at least share some "pseudocode" or the basic functionality behind this operator. So to speak: What did you try before asking? Maybe somebody would write it if some effort were put into an explanation.

Comment: Is [this](http://test.biostat.pitt.edu/biost2065/notes/note10.pdf) the sweep operator you are after?

Comment: Very close, I'm not sure why they use h_kk = +1/g_kk and my book uses h_kk = -1/g_kk, but that's the general idea. The examples that Jamie links to are from the book I'm using, so I wonder if maybe the author just made a transcription error.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be a problem with the the PDF reader in Chrome. Opening it up in a proper reader shows the minus side and it looks like everything matches Jamie's link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def sweep(g, k):
    g = np.asarray(g)
    n = g.shape[0]
    if g.shape != (n, n):
        raise ValueError('Not a square array')
    if not np.allclose(g - g.T, 0):
        raise ValueError('Not a symmetrical array')
    if k >= n:
        raise ValueError('Not a valid row number')
    #  Fill with the general formula
    h = g - np.outer(g[:, k], g[k, :]) / g[k, k]
    # h = g - g[:, k:k+1] * g[k, :] / g[k, k]
    # Modify the k-th row and column
    h[:, k] = g[:, k] / g[k, k]
    h[k, :] = h[:, k]
    # Modify the pivot
    h[k, k] = -1 / g[k, k]
    return h
```

I have no way of testing the above code, but I found an alternativee description [here](http://www-rci.rutgers.edu/~dhjones/APPLIED_LINEAR_STATISTICAL_MODELS%28PHD%29/LECTURES/LECTURE06/3-The%20sweep%20operator.pdf), which is valid for non-symmetrical matrices, which can be calculated as follows:

```
def sweep_non_sym(a, k):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = a.shape[0]
    if a.shape != (n, n):
        raise ValueError('Not a square array')
    if k >= n:
        raise ValueError('Not a valid row number')
    #  Fill with the general formula
    b = a - np.outer(a[:, k], a[k, :]) / a[k, k]
    # b = a - a[:, k:k+1] * a[k, :] / a[k, k]
    # Modify the k-th row and column
    b[k, :] = a[k, :] / a[k, k]
    b[:, k] = -a[:, k] / a[k, k]
    # Modify the pivot
    b[k, k] = 1 / a[k, k]
    return b
```

This one does give the correct results for the examples in that link:

```
>>> a = [[2,4],[3,1]]
>>> sweep_non_sym(a, 0)
array([[ 0.5,  2. ],
       [-1.5, -5. ]])
>>> sweep_non_sym(sweep_non_sym(a, 0), 1)
array([[-0.1,  0.4],
       [ 0.3, -0.2]])
>>> np.dot(a, sweep_non_sym(sweep_non_sym(a, 0), 1))
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  5.55111512e-17,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: I have a problem with the line "In the section "if not np.testing.assert_allclose(g - g.T, 0):". When I use g = np.array([[2,4],[4,3]]), g -g.T == np.zeros(2) gives the expected result. But sweep(g,0) returns "ValueError: Not a symmetrical array"

Comment: @BKay Try it now, the right thing to use there is `np.allclose`, I also corrected a typo in the last assignment before the return.

Comment: It works now. No ideas what the non-symmetric version is for but I don't need that. Thanks.