# Is there a python equivalent of R's sweep function for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, r, multidimensional-array

I need an equivalent for sweep function but to work on multidimensional arrays rather than dataframe

For Example when called the following code:

```
x <- array(1, dim=2:4)
y <- array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), dim=c(2,3))
sweep(x, MARGIN = c(1,2), y,FUN='*')
```

The result is:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

What is the equivalent for sweep code in Python? Are there any builtin functions that could help?

Comment: Unsure whether it has been implemented in a standard library since, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767435/python-implementation-of-statistical-sweep-operator) seems to have an implementation

Comment: The link provided was a python answer. The equivalent would be to iterate over a chosen dimension, applying the STATS according to a function to each element of the dimension. As `sweep`. Roughly 2 for loops should be necessary.

Comment: Numpy has a functional programming section that might be applicable: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.functional.html

Comment: I don't have a complete solution, but you should look at [broadcasting](https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/) and reshaping rules; e.g. `import numpy as np;
x = np.ones((2,3,4));
y = np.array(((1,2,3),(4,5,6)));
(x.reshape((4,2,3))*y)`